# use Column values of Dataframe to fecth data from List

Tags: dataframe, list, pyspark, databricks, col

I want to get the weekday from the list passing index into the already defined list, but index value will come from a dataframe column.

Issue is in last line where it is showing *list indices must be integers or slices, not Column*
Any idea how to pass the indices to list from dataframe column value?
thanks in advance...

Here is my code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col, lit,current_date,datediff,date_add,dayofweek
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
rdd = sc.parallelize(\[(1,)\])
df = rdd.toDF('Dummy int')
df = df.withColumn("Start Date",to_date(lit('01/08/2023'),'dd/mm/yyyy'))\
       .withColumn("End Date",current_date())\
       .withColumn("Days",datediff(col("End Date"),col("Start Date")))
no_of_days = df.collect()\[0\]\[3\]
df.show()

weekdayList = \['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'\]
df_days = spark.range(no_of_days).alias("no_of_days")
df_days.show(2)
df_days = df_days.join(df).withColumn("Date",date_add(col("Start Date"),col("id").cast("int")))\
                 .withColumn("Weekday",dayofweek(col("Date")))\
                 .withColumn("WeekdayStr",weekdayList\[col("Weekday").cast(IntegerType())%7\])
```

Comment: No, Data Bricks community edition